# Jquery detect li status change

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I am using gravity forms to display some options and hide others. My html structure is as follows

```
<li id="field_7_186" class="gfield gfield_price gfield_price_7_176 gfield_option_7_176 field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label">Additional Services</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox"><ul class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_7_186"><li class="gchoice_7_186_1">
                            <input name="input_186.1" type="checkbox" onclick="gf_apply_rules(7,[99]);" onkeypress="gf_apply_rules(7,[99]);" value="Remote KVM|75" id="choice_7_186_1" tabindex="20">
                            <label for="choice_7_186_1" id="label_7_186_1" price=" +CHF 75.00">Remote KVM<span class="ginput_price"> +CHF 75.00</span></label>
                        </li></ul></div></li>
<li id="field_7_99" class="gfield gfield_html gfield_html_formatted gfield_no_follows_desc field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible" style="display: none;"><p class="monthly"> * Remote KVM Incurs setup fee of CHF 75 and no monthly fee</p></li>
```

The second `li` with ID `field_7_99` is in the `display:none` state. Whenever a user clicks the first checkbox with ID `field_7_186` it shows the second `li`. I need a JQuery code to detect the changes in "real time" if the second `li` is displayed or not. I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#field_7_99').on('change', function() { 
    if($(this).is(':visible')) {
        console.log('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

Can somebody help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to add the logic to the click handler for `field_7_186` element?

Comment: you want to bind to a click event - change events are only for things like radios, selects and checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing this to a page you don't control, after the fact, since obviously if you control the page, just put whatever logic you need to happen in the `gf_apply_rules` handler called via that `onclick` attribute.

Simply hook click on the checkbox, wait a tick, and then check the `li`'s state:

```
$("#field_7_186 input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($("#field_7_99").is(":visible")) {
            // It's visible...
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Why the `setTimeout`? Because different browsers will handle a modern event handler and that `onclick` attribute-style handler differently in terms of timing. You need to be sure your code runs *after* that attribute-style handler.